# Why do we use RMS instead of average for average Kinetic energy?

Tags: atomic-physics

The formula for average Kinetic energy is $1/2 MVrms^2$

But why isn't it $1/2MVavg^2$? Average should be *average* right?

Comment: Compare with this: What is the average area of 3 squares with side lengths 4 m, 6 m and 8 m. Would it be $\left(\frac{(4+6+8)\ \text m} 3\right)^2=36\ \text m^2$ ?

Comment: RMS means "root mean square."  You do not have any root in the formula for average kinetic energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a numerical example would help.

Suppose that a ball of mass 1.00 kg has these speeds after being hit by a bat on 3 occasions: 6.00 m s$^{-1}$, 8.00 m s$^{-1}$, 10.00 m s$^{-1}$. The corresponding kinetic energies of the ball are 18.0 J, 32.0 J and 50.0 J. So the mean energy is 33.3 J. You can easily check that this is equal to $\frac 12 m \langle v^2\rangle$.

The mean speed,$\langle v\rangle$, is 8.0 m s$^{-1}$. Therefore $\frac 12 m \langle v\rangle^2 = 32.0\ \text J$. This is not the mean kinetic energy (33.3 J)!

Answer (score 3):

The average kinetic energy is
$$\left<\frac{1}{2}m v^2\right> = \frac{1}{2}m \left<v^2\right> \equiv \frac{1}{2}mv_{rms}^2$$

where the angle brackets denote the ensemble average and we use the definition $v_{rms} \equiv \sqrt{\langle v^2\rangle}$.

Put differently, the average kinetic energy is by definition equal to one half times the particle mass times the *average of the squared velocity*; you propose that it should be one half times the particle mass times the *square of the average velocity*, and these quantities are not the same.  Indeed,
$$\langle v^2\rangle - \langle v\rangle^2 \equiv \sigma_v^2$$
is the definition of the variance in the velocity distribution, which is always nonnegative.  As a result, your proposal would underestimate the average kinetic energy.

Answer (score 0):

Try {v} = {-10, 10} and {v} = {0, 10} in some units, each in three ways. Do out each $T=.5mv^2$, add, and divide; find and plug in the rms velocity; and find and plug in the average velocity.